# Not able to connect to JDBC Driver in my Advanced Java Program(J2EE)

Tags: jdbc, jakarta-ee, mysql-connector

Hi I am using connector/j for connecting mysql database in my Advance Java Program.
But I am getting exception:- **Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**
But when I run the same coding for my core java program I am able to connect with the database.
I think I am missing something file that I need to add in my web directory.
I am doing this first time please help me and the code is as follows:-

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> myconnect(String url, String user, String pwd) {
Connection con = null;
ArrayList<String[]> result  = new ArrayList();
String[] details            = new String[2];

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            //con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///mysql", "root", "secret");

    if(!con.isClosed()){
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL server...");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT user,host FROM user WHERE user = 'root'");
        while(rs.next()){
                        details[0]  = rs.getString("user");
                        details[1]  = rs.getString("host");
                        result.add(details);
        }
    }

}catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}finally {
    try{
        if(con != null)
            con.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){}
            return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds as though you're missing the mysql connector jar-file in the folder [webproject]/WEB-INF/lib. if this didn't help you, please provide more information on how you deploy your web project :)

Comment: hi davogotland, you guessed right I didn't added connector jar-file in the library. Thanks for that but now it is showing **Communications Link Failure** as an exception I think something like registering the driver is missing. I don't know the concept of registering driver can u please tell me how ? Thanks in advance

Comment: communication link failure is an error coming from the driver, so this means that it's registered :) the error usually means that your database isn't running. you should post a new question about this. and also, you should accept my answer since it solved your problem :)

Comment: but server is running buddy now i started using mm.mysql driver and now getting communication failure during handshake as an exception. my problem is still there I am not able to connect to the database in J2EE and I don't from where to accept the answer :) as I am newbie. ;)

Comment: wat i was missing is that I hadn't configured my.ini file now I did and saved the driver file in library as you said and it's completed now. Conflict resolved. Thanks Buddy now I am accepting your answer as you helped partial to my problem ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.*;
class AccountsStoringApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:server","hr","hr");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int c=st.executeUpdate("insert into account values(1003,'RAHIM',6800)");
        System.out.println(c+ "account stored Succesfully");
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```